# Export Datatable with more than two hundred thousand rows to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to export a datatable to excel in my application. But my datatable consists of more than 2 two hundred thousand records and i am able to write only 65536 records to the excel.

After searching a lot on google, came to know that only 65536 records can be written to excel for versions earlier than 2007.

If we can write more than 65536 records to excel please let me know

I am not using microsoft office lib in my application
I am using a class of my own which writes a table to excel

Here is my excel class

public class ExcelWrite
    {
        private Stream stream;
        private BinaryWriter writer;

```
    private ushort[] clBegin = { 0x0809, 8, 0, 0x10, 0, 0 };
    private ushort[] clEnd = { 0x0A, 00 };


    private void WriteUshortArray(ushort[] value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            writer.Write(value[i]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ExcelWriter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream.</param>
    public ExcelWrite(Stream stream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    }
    public ExcelWrite()
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the text cell value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row">The row.</param>
    /// <param name="col">The col.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The string value.</param>
    public void WriteCell(int row, int col, string value)
    {
        ushort[] clData = { 0x0204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int iLen = value.Length;
        byte[] plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        clData[1] = (ushort)(8 + iLen);
        clData[2] = (ushort)row;
        clData[3] = (ushort)col;
        clData[5] = (ushort)iLen;
        WriteUshortArray(clData);
        writer.Write(plainText);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the integer cell value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row">The row number.</param>
    /// <param name="col">The column number.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public void WriteCell(int row, int col, int value)
    {
        ushort[] clData = { 0x027E, 10, 0, 0, 0 };
        clData[2] = (ushort)row;
        clData[3] = (ushort)col;
        WriteUshortArray(clData);
        int iValue = (value << 2) | 2;
        writer.Write(iValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the double cell value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row">The row number.</param>
    /// <param name="col">The column number.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public void WriteCell(int row, int col, double value)
    {
        ushort[] clData = { 0x0203, 14, 0, 0, 0 };
        clData[2] = (ushort)row;
        clData[3] = (ushort)col;
        WriteUshortArray(clData);
        writer.Write(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the empty cell.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row">The row number.</param>
    /// <param name="col">The column number.</param>
    public void WriteCell(int row, int col)
    {
        ushort[] clData = { 0x0201, 6, 0, 0, 0x17 };
        clData[2] = (ushort)row;
        clData[3] = (ushort)col;
        WriteUshortArray(clData);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Must be called once for creating XLS file header
    /// </summary>
    public void BeginWrite()
    {
        WriteUshortArray(clBegin);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends the writing operation, but do not close the stream
    /// </summary>
    public void EndWrite()
    {
        WriteUshortArray(clEnd);
        writer.Flush();
    }
    public void exporttoExcel(DataTable table,string filename)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

            dt = table;

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                FileStream stream = File.Open("C:/Application/" + filename + ".xls", FileMode.Create);

                ExcelWrite excelWriter = new ExcelWrite(stream);
                //AB_MISreports.Util.ExcelWrite excelWriter = new AB_MISreports.Util.ExcelWrite(stream);
                excelWriter.BeginWrite();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    excelWriter.WriteCell(0, i, dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        excelWriter.WriteCell(j + 1, i, dt.Rows[j][i].ToString());
                    }
                }

                excelWriter.EndWrite();
                stream.Close();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".xls");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile("C:/Application/" + filename + ".xls");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

            dt.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a database if your row count is that high. Excel can connect to sql server as a data source

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using?

Comment: that limit is applicable to older versions of excel (2003 and earlier). Consider wrting to multiple sheets or using a newer version.

Comment: @nunespascal I am getting the datatable from the database only. actually, my requirement is to generate a report from UI for the data in my sql server.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer i cannot opt for the multiple sheets

Comment: @Cherry 200000 records would be tedious for a user to go through in a report. If its meant to be imported into another db, formats like csv would be simpler.

Comment: @nunespascal ya i completely accept it, but cant help my requirement is in such a way...:( so only trying to fulfill the need .

Answer (score 3):

These are the official limits. Excel 2007 supports both .xls and .xlsx format files, are you sure you are writing the newer file format type? It might not be a viable option for you, but we use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com) to handle spreadsheet creation.

Excel 2003 .xls - 65,536 rows
(http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)

Excel 2007 .xlsx - 1,048,576 rows
(http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx)

Excel 2010 .xlsx - 1,058,576 rows
(http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx)

Comment: can u provide me the code to create .xlsx files.. without using any 3rd party dll's

Comment: Sorry @Cherry, I can't - We used a third party tool so we didn't have to go to the trouble of writing the code ourselves :)

Answer (score 0):

please try chaning the format format from ".xls" to ".xlsx"
FileStream stream = File.Open("C:/Application/" + filename + ".xlsx", FileMode.Create);